# How to find specific matches in a string using regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I have strings like

`View_Export_US_Horizontals_Ultimate_DirectionalSurveys`

I want to extract matches like

```
[["US_Horizontals", "Ultimate", "DirectionalSurveys"]] //String Ultimate may or may not be present
```

I have the following RegEx, `/^View_Export_(US\_(GoM|Horizontals|Onshore))((_Ultimate)?)_(\w+)/`

but i get the following matches array

```
[["US_Horizontals", "Horizontals", "_Ultimate", "_Ultimate", "DirectionalSurveys"]]
```

How do i skip strings like `Horizontals` & `_Ultimate` and just get an array like

`[["US_Horizontals", "Ultimate", "DirectionalSurveys"]]`

Or

`[["US_Horizontals", "DirectionalSurveys"]]`

Comment: The use of `\w` in the last group is a bit tricky if the purpose is to evaluate the string for the right amount of underscores. Maybe use something like `^View_Export_(US_(?:GoM|Horizontals|Onshore))_(?:(Ultimate)_)?([A-Za-z]+)$` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```rb
\AView_Export_(US_(?:GoM|Horizontals|Onshore))(?:_(Ultimate))?_(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6gqYJ6/1). *Details*:

- `\A` - start of string (`^` in Ruby regex means start of any line)
- `View_Export_` - a fixed string
- `(US_(?:GoM|Horizontals|Onshore))` - Group 1: `US_` string and then either `GoM`, `Horizontals` or `Onshore` words
- `(?:_(Ultimate))?` - an optional sequence of an underscore and an `Ultimate` word
- `_` - an underscore
- `(\w+)` - Group 3: any one or more word chars.

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/oOOxIg):

```rb
string = "View_Export_US_Horizontals_Ultimate_DirectionalSurveys"
rx = /\AView_Export_(US_(?:GoM|Horizontals|Onshore))(?:_(Ultimate))?_(\w+)/
one, two, three = string.match(rx).captures

puts one   #=> US_Horizontals
puts two   #=> Ultimate
puts three #=> DirectionalSurveys
```

Comment: @opensource-developer One note: if the `third` variable must not contain `_` chars, replace `(\w+)` with `([^\W_]+)` at the end of the pattern. If the string must end there, append `\z` at the end of the pattern to require end of string (`$` matches end of a line in Ruby regex).